# Encrypting Local Data stored in PouchDB

Tags: pouchdb

Is it possible to encrypt the local data in PouchDB?

Does anyone have an example?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, yet, but I was going to test filter-pouch with sjcl.js crypto library here: https://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [filter-pouch](https://github.com/nolanlawson/filter-pouch) to transform the documents as they are stored. There's an example of encryption in the README.

Unfortunately that example only works in Node.js, since [WebCrypto is still not well-supported in most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cryptography), but there's been some effort to port Node.js crypto to the browser  with [crypto-browserify](https://github.com/dominictarr/crypto-browserify), so you could try that.

Comment: Thanks for that - Its possible I might have to use node-webkit along with pouch so that might be a more robust option - the encryption is critical.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and success to encrypt the Pouch database with sjcl and filter-pouch as ingo suggested.
Here are what finally worked:

```
app.db
.transform({
  incoming: function (doc) {
    if( doc._id.includes("_design") )
      return doc ;
    Object.keys(doc).forEach(function (field) {
      if ( (field !== '_id') && (field !== '_attachments') && (field !== '_rev') && (field !== '_revisions')&& (field !== '_conflicts') ) {
        let aux = JSON.stringify( doc[field] ) ;
        try{
            doc[field] = sjcl.encrypt( app.usuario_logueado.clave_sjcl, aux )  ;
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e) ;
        };

      }
    });
    return doc;
  },
  outgoing: function (doc) {
    if( doc._id.includes("_design") )
      return doc ;
    Object.keys(doc).forEach(function (field) {
      if ( (field !== '_id') && (field !== '_attachments') && (field !== '_rev') && (field !== '_revisions')&& (field !== '_conflicts') ) {


        try{

            doc[field] = JSON.parse( sjcl.decrypt( app.usuario_logueado.clave_sjcl, doc[field] ) ) ;
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e) ;
        };

      }
    });
    return doc;
  }
});
```

hope this help :)